# How can I plot regions using HighCharts GeoMaps?

Tags: charts, highcharts, highmaps, geomap

I am using HighCharts GeoMaps. I am interested in plotting following regions on World map:

- East Asia & Pacific
- Europe & Central Asia
- Latin America & Caribbean
- Middle East & North Africa
- North America
- South Asia

Had anybody tried this before? Please provide a fiddle if anybody has a solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

**Edit:**

I explored highmaps examples and I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tejaspchordiya/79hhadh9/) to resolve the issue. In above fiddle, the regions are getting plotted incorrectly, also complete world map is not rendered. Can somebody point out where I am going wrong?

```
$(function () {

// Prepare demo data
var data = [
    {
        "region": "South America",
        value: 3
    },
  {
        "region": "East Asia & Pacific",
        value: 10
    },
  {
        "region": "Europe & Central Asia",
        value: 12
    },
  {
        "region": "Latin America & Caribbean",
        value: 8
    },
  {
        "region": "Middle East & North Africa",
        value: 9
    },
  {
        "region": "North America",
        value: 20
    },
  {
        "region": "South Asia",
        value: 17
    }
];


// Initiate the chart
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        joinBy: ["region-wb","region"],
        allAreas: true,
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: Did you explored http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo highmap examples?

Comment: You can also look at HighMaps map collection http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/

Answer (score 0):

Is this the method you searching for ?

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-maps